# Andengine, tiled texture sizes need to be powers of 2?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

Plain texture sizes in OpenGL should be powers of 2.. okay. But how to be with Tiled textures.

We need to apply power of 2 to whole texture or for a one single tile inside of this image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short and direct answer: no, andengine tiled textures don't need to be power of 2 if you're using opengl >= 2.0.

Comment: In most cases, this is true. But there still exists exception. For example, when you use TextureOption.REPEATING_XXXX in AndEngine, the texture size still need to be POT.